# tables are not saving onto my parse server?

Tags: java, parse-server

my server is set up and accessed through SSH, but now trying to connect to the parse server and same content I'm getting this error "com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure"

public class StarterApplication extends Application {

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("**********")
            .clientKey("**************")
            .server("http://**********/parse/")
            .build()
    );
```

and in activity

```
ParseObject score = new ParseObject("Score");
    score.put("username", "dwayne");
    score.put("score", 45);
    score.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // OK
                Log.i("Success", "We saved the score");
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

trying to get it to record into my AWS parse server and nothing gets saved

Comment: You should not share your server address and keys to the internet. If you launch a Parse Dashboard and set it to connect to this server, does it work?

Comment: the parse dashboard works but nothing gets recorded

Comment: What do you mean by "it works"? Are you able to create a new class for example?

Comment: it works is saying my dashboard works to let me know im inside my parse, but no fields are occupied or new ones have been created

Comment: Are you able to create a new class using the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you posted the index.js to compare your server settings.

Depending on your server setting, you might need to use http**s** instead of http in the server url.

```
 .server("https://**********/parse/")
```